# Как импортировать класс в проект из другого проекта в Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Имеется два проекта в Intellij Idea, как импортировать класс/классы одного проекта в другой? Я для этого должен собрать `jar` одного проекта и добавить как библиотеку в структуру другого?

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас проект как библиотека будет использоваться то можно и jar. А если Вам нужно всего 2 - 3 класса из другого проекта то проще скопировать и вставить.

Comment: У меня в одном проекте есть синглтон класс, сущность которого мне надо использовать в другом проекте, как быть?

Comment: Ну так и в чем проблема? Скопировали и вставили в свой проект и обращаетесь уже непосредственно. Или Вам нужно взаимодействие между программами?

Comment: Да, потому что тот класс синглтон загружает и хранит некоторую информацию из базы данных, к которой подключен второй проект

Comment: для лучшего понимания - код в студию, но по сути не имеет значение где будет запущен Ваш синглтон в первом, во втором или в обоих проектах сразу.